# javascript not loading

Tags: javascript

Here is what I've done so far

in `functions.php`

```
function imk_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'bootstrap_js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        array('jquery'),
        '3.3.5',
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'plugin_js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/plugins.js',
        array(''),
        '1.0',
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'bskit_js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bskit-scripts.js',
        array(''),
        '1.0',
        true
    ); 
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'imk_scripts' );
```

in `footer.php`

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>         
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/bskit-scripts.js"></script>
```

but the scripts are not loading... 
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: why are you manually inserting scripts in `footer.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to add scripts in `footer.php` manually.

Secondly, if there are no script dependencies, you have to declare empty array:

`array()`, rather than `array('')`.

Due this mistake scripts are not loading except Bootstrap.

The correct code is:

```
function imk_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'bootstrap_js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        array('jquery'),
        '3.3.5',
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'plugin_js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/plugins.js',
        array(),
        '1.0',
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'bskit_js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bskit-scripts.js',
        array(),
        '1.0',
        true
    ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'imk_scripts' );
```

Comment: @user21705, please let other people know that the problem is solved. To do this please [mark this answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).